# Reformat JSON object

Tags: json, vue.js, object

I have a object like this.

```
sliderArray: 
[
  "../assets/slides/1.jpg",
  "../assets/slides/2.jpg",
]
```

Can I reformat it like this in Vue?

```
sliderArray2: 
[
  {url: require("../assets/slides/1.jpg")},
  {url: require("../assets/slides/2.jpg")},
]
```

Comment: Yes you can. Use `Array.prototype.map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with a `map`, which applies the same function to every element of an array

```js
let obj = { sliderArray: [
    "../assets/slides/1.jpg",
    "../assets/slides/2.jpg",
  ]
};

function formatArray(a) {
  return a.map(x => { return { url: require(x) } });
}

obj.sliderArray = formatArray(obj.sliderArray);
```